# Getting rid of overfull in epigraph

Tags: memoir, epigraphs

I'm getting an overfull warning: `Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--14`. How may I get rid of the warning? I want to keep the epigraph alignment as "justified". I don't get the warning if I get rid of the line `\renewcommand{\textflush}{justify}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e,epigraph}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{justify}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}{Cicero}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if, instead if `lipsum`, you write text in the language that you will be using for the document? It is possible that your TeX installation did not download the hyphenation patterns for Latin. Depends on what you have. But presumably you do have the patterns for your own language (be sure to set the language).

Comment: @rallg missing hyphenation is highly unlikely to give an exact 15pt overfull. Also the example is using US English hyphenation patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indenting a full width rule by `\parindent` (15pt) so it is too wide by that much as can be seen in the output.

[image]

You should never need `ragged2e` environment `justify`, the `epigraph` manual documents `flushepinormal` should be used, but that gives an error here as the package is not really loaded, the log shows

`Package enumerate [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.`

So instead you can use an equivalent (empty) environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e,epigraph}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{empty}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent X\dotfill X


\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}{Cicero}

\end{document}
```